# How to wait before another method is called with RxJava

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

For example I am starting a activity which finishes and returns a result, which is returned by the method `onActivityResult`. How can I wait before the result is provided by the `onActivityResult` and then continue my reactive stream?

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // receiving result here
    }

    private Single<Data> loadData() {
        return Remote.getInstance().getData()
                .flatMap(data -> {
                    // do something
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                }) // how can I receive the result from the onActivityResult here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's say, where you currently have the comment "// how can I receive the result from..., you want to do "something". Why would you not continue the activity "something" inside the onActivityResult method?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible for example by using a `PublishSubject` that would notify in `onActivityResult()` and to which you'd `flatMap()` to in your original call, **but** I'd strongly advice against this. Here is why:

When your `Activity` receives an `onActivityResult()`, it might have been just recreated from scratch, because of a configuration change, memory pressure or anything else that happened in the meantime. This means that your `Single` subscription is either no longer active (if you properly unsubscribed from it `onDestroy()` or better in `onStop()`) or leaked the previous activity instance to what it is still attached to (in case you did not unsubscribe).

So, instead the stream (and the aforementioned `PublishSubject`) should probably live inside a component that survives activity recreation, like a retained fragment and you should call into that in `onActivityResult()` to notify your stream about the results. Here is [some example](https://github.com/krpiotrek/RetainFragmentSample) how retained fragments and RxJava can work together.